# Failure sending email ERROR Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

i cannot seem to send an email from the smtp.gmail.com server. Have tried this at home and it worked but now it didnt work in the office. I don't know if it has something to do with my code or the server. Have disabled firewall. Have absolutely no clue WHY!

code below:

```
public void sendemail(string toEmail, string Subject, string Body)
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPFrom"]);
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmail));
            msg.Subject = Subject;
            msg.Body = Body;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx999+");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            List<string> multipleImage = new List<string>();
            multipleImage = FindMultipleImageLocationandFileName(Body);
            try
            {
                client.Send(msg);
            }
            catch (SmtpException err)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(err.Message);
            }
        }
```

Under `Web.config`

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="xxx@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="xxx@gmail.com" password="xxx999+" defaultCredentials="true" enableSsl="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: error is Failure to send Email.

Comment: if it is not working in ur office then there might be something which is stopping to send the mail across the domain. Please contact ur administrator for more information about anything which has been blocked

Comment: thanks! will reaffirm by trying it again at home.